# The method decodeByteArray(byte[], int, int) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (byte[][], int, int)

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, camera

I put the it in the AsyncTask but got this error.

The method decodeByteArray(byte[], int, int) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (byte[][], int, int)

```
private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(params, 0,params.length);

        return null;
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: why do you try to send byte[][] ? you should have one dimensional byte array to refer an image. I think you should send params[0]. it is just asyntask pattern. second dimension refers number of parameter. it accepts multiple parameter. if you send just params[] to that, you can call it with byte[0].

Comment: most probably, Jason's solution will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

`Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(params[0], 0,params[0].length);`

`params` is itself an array and therefore you need to specify an index.